# Connection string for connecting to SQL Server on Ubuntu

Tags: sql-server, odbc, sqlcmd

Consider this scenario.

- SQL Server is running on ubuntu
- Able to connect through Azure Data Studio
- Able to connect through sqlcmd

  ```
  sqlcmd -S 192.168.99.100,31433 -U sa -P S0mePassw0rd -d friends 
         -Q "SELECT TOP 5 * FROM dbo.users;"
  ```

But I'm not able to connect through C code using ODBC from the local machine.

```
retcode = SQLDriverConnect(hdbc, NULL, connectionstring, 
                           SQL_NTS, outstr, sizeof(outstr), &outstrlen, SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT);

retcode = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hdbc, &hstmt);
CHECK_ERROR(retcode, "SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT)",
```

`SQLDriverConnect` returns -1 and `SQLAllocHandle` fails.

It's probably a faulty connection string but I've tried hundred different ones without success.

Latest is

```
Server=friends.laurijssen.local,31433;UID=sa;PWD=S0mePassw0rd;
```

What should be the correct string to connect to 192.168.100.99 (laurijssen.local) on port 31433 and database friends?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try

```
Server=laurijssen.local,31433;database=friends;UID=sa;PWD=S0mePassw0rd;
```

or

```
Server=192.168.100.99,31433;database=friends;UID=sa;PWD=S0mePassw0rd;
```

The `server=` part should be just the server name (machine name) or IP address - plus port, if a custom port is used; the database should be specified separately with a `database=` key

For reference, see https://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-sql-server-odbc-driver/

Answer (score 1):

This line worked for me on local connection:

> **Server=.,34567;database=DatabaseName;UID=sa;PWD=YourPassword;**